# Windows 7 - Applications don't show up in volume mixer

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

Recently, I had a problem with NTFS partition with Windows 7, but after running 'chkdsk /f C:', it did some fixes and everything went back to normal - except now apps playing sounds don't show up in mixer and play no sound. Sound card and drivers work, I can run Realtek HD Audio Manager and press 'Audio Test' and then the sound is playing from speakers (and HD Audio Manager is listed in Volume Mixer). But no other app (Firefox with youtube flash, Spotify, WMP, VLC) ever shows up in the mixer. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try a `sfc /scannow` (System File Check) to try and repair possibly corrupted system files and see if that helps any.

Comment: Should I run this from recovery mode? i get "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation" at 53%

Comment: Yes try it again in Safe Mode, if it continues, then you have bigger problems. :(  Backup all your important data now.  Quickest fix for the non-tech-savvy: Test your disks using the drive manufacturer's diagnostics utilities and if they come up clean, format and reinstall Windows.  Anything more detailed than that will require much more detail from you, and could easily go beyond the scope of Super User's Q&A format.

Comment: [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/929833)